# Viewing the inside of cuboid intersections

Tags: graphics3d, regions, polyhedra

[image: Four Cuboids]

I have a number of cuboids intersecting as illustrated. I would like to see their intersection, almost the view from inside. Setting the `ViewPoint` to `{0,0,0}` does not reveal much of the structure.
Is there some way to visualize this with clever `Graphics[]` options, or must I compute the convex polyhedron
that is the intersection of the cuboids (which is really what I want to see)?

**Solved by Jens:**

[image: Cuboids4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can in principle be done using `RegionPlot3D`. But to get sharp edges, one needs to crank up the number of `PlotPoints`. Here is an example with four cubes that doesn't take too long to plot:

```
n = 4;

insideCube[pt_, l_] := And @@ Thread[Abs[pt] < l]

rotations = 
 MapThread[
  RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, {Cos[#1] Sin[#2], Sin[#1] Sin[#2], 
      Cos[#2]}}] &, RandomReal[{0, Pi}, {2, 4}]]

(*
==> {{{0.701529, 0.148251, -0.69705}, {0.148251, 0.926364, 
   0.346226}, {0.69705, -0.346226, 0.627892}}, {{0.989833, 
   0.065586, -0.12621}, {0.065586, 0.576913, 
   0.814168}, {0.12621, -0.814168, 0.566746}}, {{0.999495, -0.0316019,
    0.00319107}, {-0.0316019, -0.979314, 
   0.199866}, {-0.00319107, -0.199866, -0.979818}}, {{0.18502, 
   0.225404, -0.956536}, {0.225404, 0.937659, 
   0.264555}, {0.956536, -0.264555, 0.122679}}}
*)

rotatedCubes = 
 Or @@ MapThread[
   insideCube[#1.{x, y, z}, #2] &, {rotations, 
    RandomReal[{1, 1.1}, n]}]

(*
==> (Abs[0.701529 x + 0.148251 y - 0.69705 z] < 1.02814 && 
   Abs[0.148251 x + 0.926364 y + 0.346226 z] < 1.02814 && 
   Abs[0.69705 x - 0.346226 y + 0.627892 z] < 
    1.02814) || (Abs[0.989833 x + 0.065586 y - 0.12621 z] < 1.04828 &&
    Abs[0.065586 x + 0.576913 y + 0.814168 z] < 1.04828 && 
   Abs[0.12621 x - 0.814168 y + 0.566746 z] < 
    1.04828) || (Abs[0.999495 x - 0.0316019 y + 0.00319107 z] < 
    1.0917 && Abs[-0.0316019 x - 0.979314 y + 0.199866 z] < 1.0917 && 
   Abs[-0.00319107 x - 0.199866 y - 0.979818 z] < 
    1.0917) || (Abs[0.18502 x + 0.225404 y - 0.956536 z] < 1.02296 && 
   Abs[0.225404 x + 0.937659 y + 0.264555 z] < 1.02296 && 
   Abs[0.956536 x - 0.264555 y + 0.122679 z] < 1.02296)
*)

RegionPlot3D[rotatedCubes, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 
  2}, PlotPoints -> 120, Mesh -> False]
```

[image: cubes]

To cut through the shape and see the inside, you'd have to add another condition to `RegionPlot3D` or you can restrict the `PlotRange` as in this example:

```
Show[%, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 0}}]
```

[image: cut plot]

Comment: To plot "the convex polyhedron that is the *intersection* of the cuboids", you should define `rotatedCubes` as the `And` of all of them, no?

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes, but I looked at the picture in the question and drew my conclusions  from that!

Comment: Thanks, Jens! I learned a lot from your solution!

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Region` functionality:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
c0 = Cuboid[];
r1 := RandomReal[{0, \[Pi]/3}];
r2 := RandomReal[1, 3];
t = Table[RotationTransform[r1, r2], 8];
cn = TransformedRegion[c0, #] & /@ t;

{Style[RegionIntersection@cn, Opacity[0.5, Green]]
   , Style[RegionUnion@cn, Opacity[0.3, Red]]
   } // Map[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], #}
     , Boxed -> False
     ] &] // Show
```

[image]